# Register user only for my country

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-interface

I want to register users only for my country group .I have no idea how to do this.
Should i use ip range ? if yes how can i get my country ip adddress range or is there any other way to do it ?

Please help me.

Thank You

My country name: Nepal

Comment: Take a look here: http://blog.newagesolution.net/2008/11/how-to-block-country-and-ip-addresses.html --- You will need to look up Nepal's IP range and use that accordingly.

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that someone outside of Nepal that really wants to sign up, will find a way to sign up (VPNs, Proxies) regardless of any IP based filtering?

Comment: In general it cannot be done and IP address may also not be a trustworthy action . 

Is there a way to  get the lat long position , you can foind out the location of user from that

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no effective way to determine the origin of your visitors. You could determine the IP of your visitor and determine the geo location of this IP address, that's your best bet for an internet application. But again, I could be in Spain and be using a proxy in Nepal.

If using HTML5 you can get the geographical location of your visitors...if they allow it of course. Or you could retrieve the IP address of the request and use a library (or API) to resolve the geo-location of that IP address [MaxMind](http://www.maxmind.com/en/home) is a popular one